Error 400 al ejecutar un metodo del API
Cordial saludo, actualmente estamos teniendo dificualtados dentro de nuestro codigo con el error 400. Nuestro controller cuenta con dos metodos de nuestro interes los cuales son:
using BIL2.Models;
using DAL;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BIL2.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class FlotasNetClient : ControllerBase
    {
        // 2024-08-29: Creacion de las variables a obtener del appsettings.json
        private static string? _baseUrl;
        private static string? _username;
        private static string? _sha256Concatenado;
        private static string? _company;
        private readonly Context _context;


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-08-29: Constructor de la clase donde se pasan los datos sencibles de acceso.
        /// </summary>
        public FlotasNetClient(Context context)
        {
            // 2024-08-29: Con esta variable tengo el acceso al appsettings.json para tomar informacion de alli.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            // 2024-11-02 10:54: Datos para acceder al API REST.
            _baseUrl = builder.GetSection("baseUrl").Value;
            _username = builder.GetSection("username").Value;
            _sha256Concatenado = builder.GetSection("sha256Concatenado").Value;
            _company = builder.GetSection("company").Value;
            // 2024-11-16 21:53: Para tener acceso a la estructura de la tabla para luego poder insertar datos.
            _context = context;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 2024-10-10 10:24: Obtenemos el JSON y con este, creamos la coleccion de objetos en C# para tener los datos disponibles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet("/Vehicle/Info/ByDate", Name = "GetVehicleInfoByDate")]
        public async Task<vehicleInfo[]> GetVehicleInfoByDate()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {

                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-29T06%3A35%3A00Z&enddate=2024-10-29T06%3A40%3A00Z"),
                Headers =
                {
                    { "user-agent", "vscode-restclient" },
                    { "accept", "application/json" },
                    { "user", _username },
                    { "password", _sha256Concatenado },
                    { "company", _company },
                },
            };
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se genera la pagina con los datos.
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // 2024-09-11 08:19: Con esta linea, vemos los datos en consola para hacer busquedas y ver lo que 
                // estamos recibiendo.
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                // 2024-09-13 11:19: Con esta linea se convierte la pagina llena de datos en una coleccion en C#.
                var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<vehicleInfo[]>(body);
                return deserialized;
            }
        }


        private GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(vehicleInfo info) => new GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
        {
            uniqueID = info.uniqueID,
            plate = info.plate,
            GPSDate = info.GPSDate,
            speed = info.speed,
            odometer = info.odometer,
            receivedDate = info.receivedDate,
            stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateParam,
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail,
            CANValueTotalFuel = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueFuelLevel1 = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueRPM = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueOdometer = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValuesSpeed = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueCoolantTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueAmbientAirTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueEngineHours = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            peripheralsValueMotor = info.peripheralsInfo?.peripheralsData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.peripheralsParam == "Motor")?.peripheralsValue,
            geofencePolygon = info.geofenceInfo?.geofencePolygon
        };



        [HttpPost("/Datos/Operacion/Insertar", Name = "PostDatosOperacionInsertar")]
        public async void PostDatosOperacionInsertar()
        {
            var deserialized = await GetVehicleInfoByDate();
            var gpsDatas = deserialized.Select(ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet);
            _context.GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet.AddRange(gpsDatas);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }




    }
}

Validas primero que no se presentará algun tipo de error que impidiera que el codigo compilara, lo cual se encuentra ok.
De igual forma, nuestro program.cs esta sin ningun tipo de error, el cual es:
using DAL;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(o =>
{
    //aqui se especifica la variable que contiene la cadena de conexion en el archivo appsettings.json,
    //llamado flotasdb
    //pregunta para Pablo
    //¿como tengo dos appsettings, uno de .Development y otro .Production, el Program cual escoge?
    o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("flotasdbDesarrollo"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

El sistema, genera automaticamente el archivo lanchSettings.json, que es donde notamos que estan los puertos a utilizar y las cadenas de la url. Este es el archivo que se nos genera:
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:26071",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BIL2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7275;http://localhost:5145",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Nos causo curiosidad el porque el sistema asigna los puertos 7275 y 5145 automaticamente, pensamos que de alguna forma, el sistema valida los puertos disponibles y los toma para usarlos. Con el animo de validar esto en el cmd de windows, utilizando el comando netstat -a y obtenemos lo siguiente:
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5145         ACT004418:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7275         ACT004418:0            LISTENING

Esto nos permite confirmar que de alguna forma, el sistema identifica los puertos disponibles y los utiliza.
Continuando con el proceso, compilamos el codigo y obtenos lo siguiente:
[![Imagen de swagger][1]][1]
Hasta este punto, todo se ve bien, entonces procedemos a probar el primer metodo que llamamos /Vehicle/Info/ByDate y obtenemos el siguiente error:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at BIL2.Controllers.FlotasNetClient.GetVehicleInfoByDate() in E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL2\Controllers\FlotasNetClient.cs:line 64
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Host: localhost:7275
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
:method: GET
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Referer: https://localhost:7275/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
priority: u=1, i

En este punto, no tenemos idea actualmente de como proceder, por lo cual, agradecemos su ayuda y asesoria.

Primero lo primero, ¿has visto si el request que le estás enviando al endpoint de servicios.flotasnet.es funcione en Postman u otra herramienta para probar APIs?

fredyfx, gracias por su interes en nuestra publicacion, respondiendo a la pregunta, confirmamos que previo a incluir esta linea en el codigo, validamos que funcionará, inclusive, teniamos otra aplicacion en c# donde en consola visualizabamos los datos obtenidos.

Si el request es el exactamente el mismo: endpoint + query params + headers, en teoría, debería funcionar, ¿verdad?

asi es fredyfx, la unica diferencia entre la aplicacion en la que funciono era que se mostraba en consola y en esta oportunidad, estamos buscando mostrar los datos en swagger. No se si ello es lo que presente algun tipo de novedad que deba corregirse.

Primero que nada, has leído el error? Por que el error menciona algo que no veo en el código que estás mostrando.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at BIL2.Controllers.FlotasNetClient.GetVehicleInfoByDate() 
   in E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL2\Controllers\FlotasNetClient.cs:line 64

El error está mencionando que el request es inválido, básicamente que está mal hecho. Te indica el archivo, y la línea, la cual corresponde a:
RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-29T06%3A35%3A00Z&enddate=2024-10-29T06%3A40%3A00Z")

Ahora, a la API la consultas por GetInfoVehicleByDate2.
Estás haciendo un GET para obtener datos.
Y parametizas startdate y enddate.
Pero ya viste que valores tienen estos ?
startdate=2024-10-29T06%3A35%3A00Z
enddate=2024-10-29T06%3A40%3A00Z

No parece que hay un error en cuanto al formato de la fecha acá ?

EDIT-* El OP respondió y comprobó la información, el error persiste.
Podemos validar las variables:
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_baseUrl) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sha256Concatenado) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_company))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error en la configuración: ");
    Console.WriteLine($"baseUrl: {_baseUrl ?? "NULO"}");
    Console.WriteLine($"username: {_username ?? "NULO"}");
    Console.WriteLine($"sha256Concatenado: {(_sha256Concatenado != null ? "[HASH PRESENTE]" : "NULO")}");
    Console.WriteLine($"company: {_company ?? "NULO"}");
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Faltan valores requeridos para realizar la solicitud.");
}


Hola Excorpion, gracias por  las observaciones. El proveedor del API nos indica que la fechas deben ser en el estándar ISO8601. Anteriormente hicimos las pruebas en otro aplicativo para validar la obtencion de datos, lo cual lo hicimos con esta misma linea, asi que por ello, lo dejamos de esta forma.

El estandar indica que la fecha debe ser en formato YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ, y entre la hora, van indicado los : que en tu caso estan cambiados por %, lo cual me parece un error de formato. Al usar Z estan indicando el tiempo en UTC, asi que yo creo que pasa algo durante el paso de datos, que le estan pasando mal el formato.

Excorpion, realizamos el cambio de la URL ingresando la fecha segun indicaciones, quedando asi:  RequestUri = new Uri("https://servicios.flotasnet.es:1443/api/GetInfoVehicleByDate2?startdate=2024-10-30T01:00:00Z&enddate=2024-10-30T01:05:00Z"), A pesar de ello, el sigue apareciendo el mismo error.

En la ruta, a mi me aparece otro error diferente {"Message":"User required"}

Según veo o falta algún dato no está completo. Prueba a mostrar los datos obtenidos desde el archivo appsettings.json, luego de cargarlos a sus variables. Si el error dice que el user es required, significa que no está recibiendolo o, de plano, está llegando NULL. Prueba a depurarlo Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username), "El valor de '_username' no puede ser nulo ni vacío.");

Agregué una manera para que puedan comprobar las variables al final de la publicacion.

Hola Excorpion, el api requiere los valores que mencionas, los cuales no son null en el appsettings.json y estan registrados segun indica el proveedor del API para poderlo consumir. En una aplicacion de consola, fue validado y funciona correctamente, pero al hacerlo en una aplicacion MVC donde aparece swagger como vista, es donde se esta presentando el error mencionado.

Confío en que no son null, pero no confío en que estos están llegando, por eso recomiendo la depuración paso a paso. Sin saber más código y solo con ese error, no podría decir que es otro problema.

Excorpion, para evidenciar que el aplicacion tipo consola, se logran obtener los datos, compartimos el primer objeto, el cual se obtuvo con el forma de fecha que venimos mostrando: [{"uniqueID":1116804644,"plate":"VD-227","GPSDate":"2024-10-21T06:39:18.000Z","latitude":1.18963,"longitude":-76.64931,"speed":0,"course":0,"odometer":25823.429,"receivedDate":"2024-10-21T06:39:19.000Z","stateInfo":{"stateData":{"stateParam":"11+","stateDetail":"Parado"}},"GPSQuality":1,"CANInfo":{"CANData":[{"CANParam":"fuelLevel1","CANValue":"72"},{"CANParam":"RPM","CANValue":"0"},
